# solr search by range (double)

Tags: java, search, solr, indexing

7.0.  Solr Indexing is successful. Now I am trying to sort the data with experience field which was **double** when I index the data.  Later in some blog I read, the data type double can't be sorted and you need to mention **tdouble.**  So I changed the datatype to tdouble and then restarted solr again.  I am querying solr with `totalExperience_years:[5.0 TO 5.5]` in `fq` field.  There are some 5K + data for the range I mentioned and I got only 944 which is people with experience 5.0.  So can someone give me some idea to search solr with the range.  Thanks for your help in anticipation.

Comment: did you reindex the data?

Comment: Initially I indexed with double.  Then I changed tdouble and restarted server.  I didn't reindex.

Comment: @sidgate: Do I need to reindex the whole data again .?

Comment: I deleted the indexed data now and started reindexing now.  Let me update after reindexing.  It might take some 1 hr to index the data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Any change to field type in schema.xml file will require re-indexing of complete data. That would resolve the issue.